# PyQt 5.5 QML Combobox

Tags: python-3.x, qml, qt5, qtquick2, pyqt5

I'm trying to play with PyQt 5.5 using QML (installed from source).

This is my `main.qml`:

```
Window {
 ...
 ComboBox {
  objectName: "cmbTypeCompression"
  width: 240
  height: 26
  model: ListModel {
   id: cbItems
   ListElement { text: "Banana" }
   ListElement { text: "Apple" }
   ListElement { text: "Coconut" }
 }
...
}
```

this is my code.py

```
class GUI(QApplication):
 self.app = QApplication([])
 self.engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
 self.ctx = self.engine.rootContext()
 self.ctx.setContextProperty("main", self.engine)
 self.engine.load(URL)
 self.loadForm()
 self.loadSignal()
 self.app.exec_()

 def loadSignal(self):
  obj = self.win.findChild(QObject, "btnSave")
  obj.messageRequired.connect(myFunction)

 def loadForm(self):
  self.setProp("txtCompSub", "text", config.compression.sub_folder)
  self.setProp("txtNumProtos", "text", config.compression.num_prototype)
  self.setPropList("cmbTypeCompression", "model", ["A", "B", "C"])

 def setProp(self, objName,  propName, value):
  obj = self.win.findChild(QObject, objName)
  property = QQmlProperty(obj, propName)
  property.write(value)

 def setPropList(self, objName,  propName, values):
  obj = self.win.findChild(QObject, objName)
  property = QQmlProperty(obj, propName)
  property.setModel #### <- ?????????
 ...

...
```

Well, my questions are those:

1. Does exist a better method to load my form?

With `self.win.findChild(QObject, objName)` I can get a `QObject` but not a `ComboBox` object.

2. How can I get `ComboBox` object in QML file?

with `property.read()` on `ComboBox` (`QObject`) I get a `QAbstractListModel` object.

3. How can I set a model of `ComboBox` object with previous getting of `QObject`?

To put it in a simpler way:

How can I set my custom model in `Combobox` QML with python and PyQt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
def loadForm(self):
 ...
 self.setPropList("cmbTypeCompression", "model", ["Item A", "Item B"])

def setPropList(self, objName,  propName, values):
 obj = self.win.findChild(QObject, objName)
 property = QQmlProperty(obj, propName)
 property.write(values)
```

...but I don't know if it is the best solution